# About changing the endpoint in insight API (in bitcore)

Tags: bitpay, bitcore

I am just trying to find docs on bitpay's bitcore node to change the endpoint of one of its services , which is insight-api

https://github.com/bitpay/bitcore-node

https://github.com/bitpay/insight-api

```
The API endpoints will be available by default at: http://localhost:3001/insight-api/
```

Question: Is there a way to change `localhost:3001/insight-api/` to say `localhost:3001/btcApi/` ? I understand the config file is like `SomeNode/data/bitcoin.conf`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the bitcore-node.json configuration to include these items: https://github.com/bitpay/insight-api/issues/430

Comment: Thanks, I haven't tried it yet, but it looks exactly like what I was looking for